Is there any solution for the rsync permission denied for public key?
I am setting the CI/CD for AWS ec2 instance using github actions so that as soon as I push the code it reflects to the instance. I am developing a project in laravel.
Trying to solve the error for more than 2 days but am not getting the proper solution on the internet . The image contains the error. If you have any reference for it or solution then please let me know.
Thank you in advance.
I added .github/workflow/deploy.yml file in the github repo and also added the below code.
name: Laravel Deployment to AWS EC2

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy Laravel to EC2
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      # Checkout the code
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      # Deploy files to EC2
      - name: Deploy to EC2
        uses: easingthemes/ssh-deploy@main
        env:
          SSH_PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          REMOTE_HOST: ${{ secrets.EC2_HOST }}
          REMOTE_USER: ${{ secrets.EC2_USERNAME }}
          TARGET: ${{ secrets.TARGET_DIR }}
          ARGS: "-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"

      # Ensure correct folder permissions
      - name: Set Folder Ownership on EC2
        run: |
          ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${{ secrets.EC2_USERNAME }}@${{ secrets.EC2_HOST }} << 'EOF'
          sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/my-book-mate
          EOF

      # Run Laravel artisan commands
      - name: Run Laravel Artisan Commands
        run: |
          ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${{ secrets.EC2_USERNAME }}@${{ secrets.EC2_HOST }} << 'EOF'
          cd ${{ secrets.TARGET_DIR }}
          php artisan migrate --force
          php artisan cache:clear
          php artisan config:cache
          php artisan route:cache
          EOF



What is the actual error this pipeline gives you?

can you please check, I have added the image of the error
